# App size too big IOS (Unity 3D)

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, compression, size, textures

I am currently developing an application (an arcade game) with Unity and I want to release it on iOS and Android. It is almost finished , but I have a problem : the game weights more than 600 MB on IOS. It is very high and it may deter many users to downloading my application.
The compression of my images is PVRTC 2bit and most are in PNG because I need transparency.

Here is my editor log :
[image: My editor Log]

Do you know where is the problem ? How to solve it ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Probably you already know this but just to make sure: Unity is overriding compression of all the assets (textures, audios, etc.). You can select your texture in the project tab and set the compression settings in the inspector tab. The size of the image will appear at the bottom of the inspector.

You may find [Unity's Reducing File Size](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html) interesting.

And maybe [Player Size Optimization](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-playerSizeOptimization.html) too, less probable though

Comment: Also, make sure to remove all the unused assets from the project - for some reason they are all included in the build

Comment: Tanks for your answers !